# How to get the second most occurring value(and the least occurring value) in each row in R

Tags: r

For each row in my dataframe, I want to find the second highest occurring value, as well as the least occurring value. How can i do this?

Df:

```
label v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
5     3  3  3  6  6  8
5     7  1  1  1  7  0
5     3  5  6  6  6  5
```

I want to consider all columns besides 'label'

Expected output:

```
second largest occuring     least occuring
6                           8
7                           0
5                           3
```

Edit: I have updated the example after the answer was accepted to make it less confusing

Comment: Kindly share the sample dataset or provide the reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks, can you please add the expected output so that it will be easier for us?

Comment: I assume that's a typo and the second-largest occurring value for the second row should be 1?

Comment: Gregor - that's frequency of occurring, not value

Comment: @Gregor- I believe it is correct, 1 is occuring 3 times, 2 is occuring 2 times. Hence I want the digit 2(not how many times 2 occurs)

Comment: Reading the comments are making me second guess the solutions. Are you looking for the second highest value that occurs (2,1,5) or are you looking for the value that occurs the second most number of times (2,2,5)?

Comment: the latter, looking for the value that occurs the second most number of times

Comment: I'd recommend updating your language to "second most occurring" instead of "second largest occurring" for better clarity.

Comment: Thank you, I apologize for the confounding language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another dplyr solution that is a bit more readable and handles errors for NA and instances where there are multiple occurrences of the second largest. This solution also allows you to select multiple columns using dplyr language.

```
library(dplyr)

dat = read.table(text = 'label v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
5     3  3  3  2  2  1
5     2  1  1  1  2  0
5     3  5  6  6  6  5', header = T)

second_largest <- function(x,na.rm = TRUE) {
  if(na.rm) { x <- na.omit(x) } # omit NA values
  second_largest <- x[dense_rank(x) == 2] # return all values where the rank is equal to 2nd largest
  second_largest <- max(second_largest) # keep one value out of all the second largest, or NA
  return(second_largest)
}

df <- dat %>%
  mutate(
    second_largest = select(., v1:v6) %>% apply(1, second_largest,na.rm = TRUE), # apply second_largest func to every row
    min = select(., v1:v6) %>% apply(1,min,na.rm = TRUE) # apply min to every row
  ) 

#   label v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 second_largest min
# 1     5  3  3  3  2  2  1              2   1
# 2     5  2  1  1  1  2  0              1   0
# 3     5  3  5  6  6  6  5              5   3
```

A few things to notice.

In the apply statement the 1 indicates that the function should be applied to the rows.

***Update***

If you want the value of the second most frequent number you just plug in a new function to do that.

```
second_most_frequent <- function(x, is_numeric = TRUE) {
  out <- x %>%
    table() %>% # Create a table of frequencies as characters
    as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    arrange(desc(Freq)) %>% # Arrange with frequency descending
    .[,1] %>% # Select the first column
    .[2] # select the second most frequent (WARNING: Doesn't check for ties)
  if(is_numeric){ out <- as.numeric(out) }
  return(out)
}

df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    second_most_freq = select(., v1:v6) %>% apply(1,second_most_frequent,is_numeric = TRUE)
  )

#   label v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 second_largest min second_most_freq
# 1     5  3  3  3  2  2  1              2   1                2
# 2     5  2  1  1  1  2  0              1   0                2
# 3     5  3  5  6  6  6  5              5   3                5
```

Answer (score 4):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(var, val, -label, -rowid) %>%
  group_by(rowid, val) %>%
  tally() %>%
  summarise(second_largest_occuring = val[dense_rank(n) == 2],
            least_occuring = val[n == min(n)]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-rowid)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  second_largest_occuring least_occuring
                    <int>          <int>
1                       2              1
2                       2              0
3                       5              3
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "label v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
5     3  3  3  2  2  1
                 5     2  1  1  1  2  0
                 5     3  5  6  6  6  5", header= TRUE)
```

Comment: note that the line defining `least_occuring` should read `least_occurring=val[n==min(n)]